# How to stop Version Garbage Collection

Tags: java, spring-boot, jcr, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

I am using JackRabbit oak implementation in my Spring Boot project. My application creates multiple nodes in postgres db. After every particular cycle I am deleting/removing nodes from repository and running version garbage collection by using below code:

```
RepositoryUtil.getDocumentNodeStore().getVersionGarbageCollector().gc(0, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

But for some scenarios, I have to stop running garbage collection. So Is there any way to cancel or stop running version GC?

Comment: well, there is <https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/apidocs/org/apache/jackrabbit/oak/plugins/document/VersionGarbageCollector.html#cancel--> - did you try that?

Comment: @JulianReschke I will try and will share my findings.

Comment: @JulianReschke After running version garbage collection, I have run my code with implementation of `cancel()` method from `VersionGarbageCollector`. Once cancel() method execution completed, again I started version garbage collection, but I got below error, It seems that cancel() method did not work.
`java.io.IOException: Revision garbage collection is already running
 at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.document.VersionGarbageCollector.gc(VersionGarbageCollector.java:169)`

Comment: I believe "cancel()"  only sets a flag. You'll need to wait until the thread finishes.

Comment: Yes, but got below error once thread finishes.
`org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.document.DocumentStoreException: This oak instance failed to update the lease in time and can therefore no longer access this DocumentNodeStore.`

Comment: Which version of Oak?

Comment: version: '1.10.8'

Comment: Sounds a bit like https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OAK-8089, but that was fixed earlier. Make sure that you don't shutdown the repo until the VerionGC thread is done...